# Incorrect icons on profile view

Tags: bug, status-norepro

On the top right of the profile view on the main site, the icons for *meta user* and *network profile* are incorrect. They do appear as expected when on this meta site.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I can't reproduce this. Try doing a hard refresh (Ctrl+F5 if on Windows).

Comment: I hard refreshed a few times, no change. Using Chrome on Windows 8.

Comment: Can you try to explicitly hard refresh [this image](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=14fa70d6428ecdc4a847c811afe971c0)?

Comment: Same. I can't reproduce it here (icons are correct for me).

Comment: Well, now I look foolish. The icons show correctly for me now, despite multiple refreshes yesterday.